# How to check if the floppy driver is installed?

Tags: debian, drivers, floppy

How can I check if the floppy driver is installed on my Debian system?

I already used the following commands:

```
find /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/ -name '*.ko' | grep floppy
ls -l /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/
```

But I have not found any information about a floppy driver. Are there any better commands to check if the floppy driver is installed?

Furthermore, I have checked the `/dev` directory and have found the following entry:

```
0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          12 Aug  1  2012 fd -> /proc/self/fd
```

Which, as far as I know, is the floppy disk device. Why is the floppy disk in the devices when there is no driver installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current Debian kernels do still provide the floppy driver, and

```
find /lib/modules -name floppy.ko
```

should show where it lives on disk.

```
find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -name floppy.ko
```

will determine whether the currently installed version of the currently-running kernel is built with the floppy driver as a module.

To determine whether it’s installed in the running kernel, use `lsmod`:

```
lsmod | grep floppy
```

If that outputs nothing, the module isn’t installed.

On most current (physical) systems you won’t be able to install it anyway, because most current computers no longer have a floppy controller. The various `/dev/fdX` devices will only show up if the `floppy` module is installed successfully. `/dev/fd` itself isn’t related to the floppy driver, it provides access to the current process’ file descriptors.

It is possible for a kernel to have the floppy driver built-in; to check for that, look for floppy-related messages in your boot log (`dmesg` if your system hasn’t produced too much output since it was booted), or look for `BLK_DEV_FD` in your kernel’s configuration.

Note that this driver isn’t used for USB floppy drives.

Comment: And is `find /lib/modules -name floppy.ko` a surefire way of testing if your Linux system still can support a floppy? My Arch with kernel 5.2.6 returns nothing. Have I moved to this brave new era bereft of floppies?

Comment: @terdon it doesn’t guarantee it, the driver could still be built-in, not built as a module. See the update for some more detail.

Comment: And of course there's this: https://m.slashdot.org/story/358994, leading to Github: ["This also marks the floppy driver as orphaned"](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/47d6a7607443ea43dbc4d0f371bf773540a8f8f4)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, I hear the news of the death of floppy were a bit premature: https://lwn.net/Articles/795012/